# How to process each pixel of the image use Magick.NET maximally quickly?

Tags: c#, imagemagick, magick.net

I use the lib Magick.NET for access to the image file. I need to process each pixel on image:

```
MagickImage img = new MagickImage(@"d:\TEST\110706M01000509.jpg");
PixelCollection pc = img.GetReadOnlyPixels(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);

for (int x = 0; x < pc.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < pc.Height; y++)
    {
        byte[] color = pc.GetValue(x,y);

        // SOME ACTIONS
    }
```

But, access to the color of pixels of the image (12000 X 16000) takes more than 5 minutes… How more quickly process all pixels of the image use lib Magick.NET?

Comment: It may help to put the x loop inside the y loop, because ImageMagick  internally organizes the pixels in scanlines.  In fact most if not all image formats are organized that way, too.

Comment: If the first loop by x, the second loop by y, I received next result:  
start load -> 14:51:34  
start loop -> 14:51:46  
end loop -> 14:58:53  
  
If the first loop by y, the second loop by x, I received next result:  
start load -> 15:05:56  
start loop -> 15:06:08  
end loop -> 15:12:56  
  
Improve absent. Anymore ideas?

Comment: use emgucv for that..